# When to bump a project's version number on Github

Tags: ruby, git, github, semantic-versioning

This is more of a philosophy question but I'm wondering what would be the way to go.

Ok, let's take a concrete example. I have a project on Github, it's a Ruby gem.

Usually, when I release a new version, I finalize all the features and fixes and then, create a commit with `"Bumping version to v1.2.0"` as message and containing only the Changelog update and `VERSION` constant update. The `v1.2.0` tag points to this commit.

But then...

- Should I directly bump again the version so it becomes `v1.3.0-alpha` in the repo ?
- If somewhere in the process I end up making a big change, should I then re-bump the version to `v2.0.0` ?
- Should I create a `v1.2.x` branch to work on for patch releases ?

What is your process and the good practice to use around all of this ?
Any additional advice ?

Thanks all ! :)

Comment: It's an interesting question but you should consider http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ as a better place to look for answers.

Comment: With respect to creating a 1.2.x branch, I prefer to do so lazily: that is, I'd create a 1.2.x branch from the v1.2.0 tag only at the point that I have a commit to put in that branch. I find this way, it's easier to see whether there are changes since a release. But if you're likely to use the branch, you might as well create it up front.

Comment: @MartinEllis I thought about it too :)